# Why can't CSS find my animation, when I have set what animation it should play?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have added a simple animation to my code, but for some reason I can't get it working

```
<div class="phone-center">
    <div class="phone">
    </div>
</div>


.phone-center
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.phone
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    animation: rotatephone 1.5s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes rotatephone
{
    0%
    {
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }

    50%
    {
        transform: rotate(90deg)
    }

    100%
    {
        transform: rotate(90deg)
    }
}
```

What I have noticed is that under Elements\Computed, the animation-name is empty

[[image: ComputedCSS]]

But under the Styles it looks like it can find an animation, but it has renamed the animation

[image: StylesCSS]

Any idea what could be the problem here? My site is using Vue 2 and Quasar v1, but I don't think it should have any affect on this

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue you describe with the code provided. It is working fine for me.

Comment: That `rotatephone-<number>` looks like it might be a build process thing, are you running through anything like webpack that might be affecting the final file?

Comment: @tacoshy why did you remove crucial information from the question? The fact that he's using Vue  and Quasar might be related to the issue

Comment: It also works fine in the codepen I copied the code from. I just can't seem to find a reason why it shouldn't work in my code. It's not exactly rocket science code. Chrome DevTools doesn't help me. I'm just hoping someone could help me in the right direction to find a reason it might not work

Comment: @TemaniAfif I thought about that too but thought it was not relevant to the issue. More likely that it is overwritten by something else. But you're more experienced with it. Maybe you have other ideas that you can share.

Comment: Vue might give different names to your classes and html elements. That's why it's better to use Vue's built-in animation and transition techniques. https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/animation

Answer (score -1):

After some testing, I managed to get the animation working
At first I had the animation in a vue component, this didn't work.
After moving it out of the component and onto the html page it works. So it seems like Vue is what is causing this problem
This is not perfect, but better than nothing and not an issue I want to spend to much time on

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to merge a a vanillaJS/CSS workflow with a Vue workflow. Better spend some time on a Vue tutorial if you want to do it right :)